How does Microsoft Office achieve displaying SharePoint sites in Explorer "Save As" dialog?
When saving a document in Microsoft Office you get the option to save it on SharePoint which will open a Save as dialog frame but with a custom content. How is this achieved on the programmers side? Because just entering the SharePoint web address in the normal Windows Explorer won't do anything. Is this some sort of custom extension or how does this work?

